# Template without modules

Tags: joomla-3.x, templates

Is there any template whith no module positions, just content position. I need it to make Iframe link for the component on my site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding `?tmpl=component` to your URL will render only the content position, without any of the modules.

Example: `<iframe src="http://www.yoursite.com/index.php?tmpl=component"></iframe>`

You can also customize this view if you need to add/remove CSS styles, JavaScript or other modifications. Just edit the file `templates/YOURTEMPLATE/component.php`..

Answer (score 0):

You could create a custom template for that purpose.  https://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_basic_Joomla!_template

Or you could use Master Bootstrap https://www.masterbootstrap.com/